# Deploy an ASP.net application in windows server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, windows-server-2008

I'm new to  applications deployment

I have  a  .ZIP file     (developping in asp.net mvc4   and VS2012)

i have already  instaled a  windows server 2008

what i need to deploy this application    (.NET freamwork ?,IIS? , microsoft sql server?....?)

think you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article is a good starting point. You can ignore the visual studio bit if you do not require it.

[Running Web Applications on Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.0 and Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763178%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)